# HTC One X+ is getting hot. Is it Normal?

Tags: battery, htc-one-x+

The other day my daughter was playing with wife's phone (HTC one x+) and asked me for help. When I grabbed the phone I realised that was so **HOT** that I think I could fry an egg on it. Is this normal?

Is there any tip you can give me to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. It could have been because your daughter was playing a game on the phone, or just taking up a lot of processing power. Also, having one's hands on the back of the phone also does not help. I've had this issue with multiple devices when playing games specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with the phone. Getting hot, just not a problem with hardware. 
I can solve the overheating problem just like that.
Disable all the apps that have Google in their name including Google service framework, Play and market feed back and just don't forget the boss Chrome browser. (Even if you don't use them) . Use built in Android browser. 
You will be cool, I ment your HTC